# handle xss in url with js

Tags: javascript, url, encoding, xss

I have a url parameter that could be either:
"http://www.example.net"
or:
javascript:alert(document.cookie)

if I'm using encodeURIComponent to avoid that xss attack, the legit url is ruined, and if I'm using encodeURIComponent, the xss attack is not dealt with (the colon passes). what is the best approach to avoid the xss attack and keep the url valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see it, there are two main options:

1. You can make a whitelist of allowed parameters, and don't bother with actually doing anything with the actual url being passed. In other words, you'd do something like `?url=example` and have that redirect to `http://www.example.com` if it is in the whitelist. To be clear, these are aliases, not a rule where you just assume the prefix and tld of the site. This helps make sure you are not vulnerable to [open-redirects](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Open_redirect) AND XSS.
2. If maintaining a list like this is not feasible, you can make a rule that you can only use certain domains (maybe just the same domain as the site). At the very least you can verify that the scheme is `http|https`, but you'd still be vulnerable to open-redirects, but at least they wouldn't be able to XSS your page through that parameter.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to prevent 'javascript:' protocol links, you can check with a regular expression that ensures that only http: https: or a relative url is used. It is best to white-list the allowed protocols rather than prevent forbidden ones. The encodeURIComponent function is for adding parameters to the query string of the URI which is not what I think you intend.

```
urlRE=/^(?:https?:)?[^\s:]+$/
urlRE.test("javascript:alert(document.cookie)")
//false
urlRE.test("http://www.example.net")
//true
```